# Getting documents with ID from firstore collection React

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I don't know how to get a generited by Firestsore document (shop) ID in array of shops which firebase give me back....

```
    componentDidMount() {
    let response = fire.firestore().collection('shops').
    get().
    then(snapshot => {
        const data = snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
        this.setState({
            ...this.state,
            shopsArray: data
        })
    })
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the ID of the document, use the [`DocumentSnapshot.id` property](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot#id). So something like:

```
componentDidMount() {
    let response = fire.firestore().collection('shops').
    get().
    then(snapshot => {
        snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => { console.log(doc.id); });
        ...
```

Comment: That works, but is it any simple way to include this id when i do "const data = snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());" to my data array as bonus attribute ?
I would like to have all atributes of document with this id in my array..